How can I change the namespaces in an Excel XML map?
I have an Excel sheet that exports data in an XML format. The exports are going to a public authority, and follows their format. But I have not had access to any XSD, so the XML map was once upon a time created from example data that I imported.
Now, the authority in question has changed the schema. From what I understand, the changes do not affect my application at all. Content is identical in my use case. But the two XML namespaces used have been changed, since they contain the version of the schema.
So all I need to do is to change the namespaces in the XML header. Currently, the header looks like this:
<ns3:IE815 xmlns:ns3="urn:publicid:-:EC:DGTAXUD:EMCS:PHASE4:IE815:V3.01" xmlns:ns4="urn:publicid:-:EC:DGTAXUD:EMCS:PHASE4:TMS:V3.01" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
I need to change the two occurrences of "3.01" to "3.13" for my exports to be accepted by the receiver.
But how do I do that?
I cannot figure out where in the Excel document this information is stored!
In the XML map itself, I can only see the content elements with namespace prefixes, not the full namespace string. In the list of XML maps, one of the namespaces is visible, but not possible to change.

You can rename your .xsls file to a .zip file. Unzip it, and you will find lots of XML files. And you will find  everything, including namespaces.

Thanks Yitzhak, good suggestion! I was starting to think of doing something like that. But a bit disappointing if that is the only way... If nothing more direct turns up, I will certainly try this!

Since there was no other sufggestions, I went with the suggestion from
Yitzhak Khabinsky in comment above, to unzip the Excel file and search for the pattern in the contained XML files.
Worked like a charm! Thanks again, Yitzhak!
